# In IE9 - Make white space being inserted below the grid not happen if I move the mouse away from the cell

Tags: kendo-ui, internet-explorer-9, kendo-grid

In IE9:
White space will be inserted below a kendo ui grid if I have a scroll bar
below the grid and select a cell to edit then move the mouse away and back
from the cell that is being edited.

Below are the steps:

00) Run ...htm file in IE9
01) Drag the right side of the window to the left so a horizontal scroll bar shows up at bottom of the grid.
02) Click C00 first row to edit c00 cell
03) Move the mouse away from the edit field to the next row and back
04) Notice the white space that is inserted at bottom of grid
05) If you move back and forth about 12 - 15 times the white space goes back to none. NOTE: This doesn't happen in jsfiddle IE9
-------
This doesn't happen if there is no horizontal scroll bar.
How do I make the white space being inserted below the 
grid not happen if I move the mouse away fromt the editor 
field when there is a horizontal scroll bar?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elbarto99/46q3cL5u/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var dsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data:
    [
        { // 1
        title: "Star Wars: A New Hope",
        c00: "a",
        c01: "a",
        c02: "a",
        },
        { // 2
        title: "Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back",
        c00: "b",
        c01: "b",
        c02: "b",
        },
    ],
    schema:
    {
        model:
        {
            id: "myGridID",
            fields:
            {
                title: { type: "string"  },
                c00:   { type: "string"  },
                c01:   { type: "string"  },
                c02:   { type: "string"  },
            }
        },
    }
});

// Createe a Kendo grid in DIV
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dsDataSource,
    editable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "title", title: "Title"         , width: "270px" },
        { field: "c00"  , title: "C 00"          , width: "200px" },
        { field: "c01"  , title: "C 01"          , width: "110px" },
        { field: "c02"  , title: "C 02"          , width: "110px" },

    ],

});
```

});

Comment: I got it to work. :)    I added 'height: "130px",' after "editable: true," and the white space doesn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix:

Added 'height: "130px",'

after the 
"editable: true,"
line

[jsfiddle 2nd](http://jsfiddle.net/elbarto99/46q3cL5u/2/)

```
// Createe a Kendo grid in DIV
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dsDataSource,
    // This fixes the white space problem
    height: "130px",
    editable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "title", title: "Title"         , width: "270px" },
        { field: "c00"  , title: "C 00"          , width: "200px" },
        { field: "c01"  , title: "C 01"          , width: "110px" },
        { field: "c02"  , title: "C 02"          , width: "110px" },

    ],

});
```